# Calculating quotation combinations

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have a phrase with $n$ words. I want to find out how many ways there are to put parts of this phrase in quotation marks. For example, take the phrase "I like dogs". Through brute force we can find the answer, but for $n$ much larger than 3 it gets difficult (as things tend to do).

I like dogs

"I" like dogs

I "like" dogs

I like "dogs"

"I" "like" dogs

"I" like "dogs"

I "like" "dogs"

"I" "like" "dogs"

"I like" dogs

I "like dogs"

"I like" "dogs"

"I" "like dogs"

"I like dogs"

We can see that if $n$ is 3, then there are 13 ways to divide it up. I can't seem to figure out a combinatoric way to calculate for arbitrary $n$, has anyone else done something like this before?

Comment: For sure it has to do with 2 non-nested and 2 non-crossing matchings.